# get certain property from app.config without looping

Tags: c#, .net, loops, app-config, data-access-layer

i need your help

i have app.config like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    ...
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    ...
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings />
  <userSettings>
    <MySettings>
      <setting name="Precision" serializeAs="String">
        <value>0</value>
      </setting>
    </MySettings>
  </userSettings>
  <applicationSettings>
    ...
  </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

what I need is to get 'Precision' value. how to get that without looping SectionGroups, SectionCollection?

note:
I've DAL and in my DAL need this precision to format the decimal value and the precision is managed by user(client) through the Presentation Layer. I save the precision value in app.config. The problem, the app.config is in Presentiation Layer, and I cannot use Properties.MySetting.Default.Precision to get that. (Thanks to Branko & Tim to remind me about this reason)

Comment: Is there a specific reason you can't access it as: `Properties.Settings.Default.Precision`?

Comment: sorry, i forgot to tell more deeply. I've DAL in my DAL need read that property. The problem, the app.config is in Presentiation Layer, and I cannot user Properties. thanks for the reply

Comment: Is your DAL an executable or a class library (DLL)?  If it's a DLL, it can read the settings in the calling executable's app.config file.

Comment: Thanks Tim. my DAL is Class Librabry (DLL)

Comment: @Willi - then your DAL should be able to access the properties in the calling executable's app.config.  I've done it with the `<appSettings>` section before, though I've not done it with `Properties.Settings` as Branko suggested.  As long as the DAL is referenced by the executable - if you're going presentation -> business -> data, with the business calling the data, then it won't work.

Comment: @willi, you can declare Settings in your assembly as "public" (as opposed to default "internal"), which would make them visible as `ProjectNamespace.Properties.Settings.Default.SettingName` from other projects. This can be done through the "Access Modifier" combo-box at the top of the Settings editor.

Comment: @Tim: you're right. my DAL is not referenced by the executable, I've used 3 layer, Presentation call Business(BLL) and Business call DAL. so Tim, how to solve this?

Comment: @willi - Without knowing more specifics about your design, I can think of two ways off the top of my head.  One way is to reevaluate your design and try to determine why the DAL is dependent upon information from the presentation layer (to me, that would break the idea of 3 layer design, unless you have a very good reason to do this).  The other way is to have the business layer pass the needed settings down to the data layer.  If you can expand on your question a bit more the folks here at SO can probably give some more concrete guidance/suggestions for you.

Comment: @Branko: I've change the modifier to public, but still I cannot use  ProjectNamespace.Properties.Settings.Default.SettingName in my DAL

Comment: @willi You can always make a "settings-only" project if you need to break project dependency cycles.

Comment: @Tim: Because my DAL need to format the decimal value based on the precision that managed by user(client) in Presentation Layer. the second way could solve this problem but I think it is not a good solution. so what do you think? if it is the the only way, then I'll go with the second. Thanks Tim

Comment: @Willi - Why not have your DAL return the data raw, and let the business layer take care of formatting it per the client's settings?

Comment: @Tim: yes, that's a good idea, but I must change all my code in DAL to return as data raw than list, but no problem, Thanks Tim and Thanks Branko nice to meet you friend

Answer (score 1):

I would consider "settings injection" here - like dependency injection, but for settings :)

Presumably your entry point configures the whole system... so get *it* to read all the settings from app.config, and use those when creating and configuring the DAL (and anywhere else which needs settings). The only piece of code which needs to know how to use app.config can be the entry point. Everything else can be specified via POCOs, individual constructor parameters etc.

This is good in several ways:

- Your code will be easier to test: to test different settings, just pass in different constructor arguments. No need for files etc.
- Your immediate problem is solved: the DAL no longer needs to look through the settings file
- You're isolating your configuration storage in a single place which can change if you decide to (say) use a different XML format, or an "ini"-style configuration format

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood Jon's answer correctly it looks like the following:

```
public interface IConfigurationWrapper
{
  IDictionary<string, string> Properties { get; }
  T GetSection<T>(string name) where T : ConfigurationSection;
}

public class ConfigurationWrapper : IConfigurationWrapper
{
  // implementation with with ConfigurationManager.GetSection or just placeholders
}

public interface IProduct
{
  string Name { get; }
}

public class Product : IProduct
{
  readonly IConfigurationWrapper m_configuration;

  public Product(string key, IConfigurationWrapper configuration)
  {
    m_configuration = configuration;
  }

  public string Name
  {
    get { // use m_configuration to get name from .config }
  }
}

public class ProductFactory
{
  readonly IConfigurationWrapper m_configuration;

  public ProductFactory(IConfigurationWrapper configuration)
  {
    m_configuration = configuration;
  }

  public IProduct CreateProduct(string key)
  {
    return new Product(key, m_configuration);
  }
}
```

and usage looks like:

```
var config = new ConfigurationWrapper();
var factory = new ProductFactory(config);
var product = factory.CreateProduct("myproductkey");
```

clients work with IProduct interface only, "products" layer works with IConfigurationWrapper, while wrapper works with whatever the configuration you have (.config or mocks, you can have mock products for testing too). Code above is heavily stripped part of larger system just to provide example don't get it too literally.